# (Unix/Python) Activity Monitor % CPU

Tags: python, macos, unix, multiprocessing, python-3.5

I have a project I am working on for developing a distributed computing model for one of my other projects. One of my scripts is multiprocessed, monitoring for changes in directories, decoding pickles, creating authentication keys for them based on the node to which they are headed, and repickling them. (Edit: These processes all operate in loops.)

My question is, when looking at the activity monitor in OSX, my %CPU column displays 100% for the primary processes that run the scripts. These three that are showing 100% are the manager script, and the two nodes (I am simulating the model on one machine, the intent is to move the model to a live cluster network in the future). Is this ***bad***? My system usage shows 27.50%, user 12.50%, and 65% idle.

I've attempted research myself, first, and my only thought is that these numbers display that the process is utilizing the CPU for the entire time it's alive, and is never idle.

Can I please get some clarification?

[image: OSX Activity Monitor]

**Update based on comments:**
My processes run in an endless loop, monitoring for changes to files in their respective directories, in order to receive new 'jobs' from the manager process/script (a separate computer in the cluster in the project's final implementation). Maybe there is a better way to be waiting for I/O in this form that doesn't require so much processor time?

Comment: I agree your conclusion. Do you have any endless loops there? If you monitor IO and your timeout is 0 it will timeout immediately and you will be busy 100% computing python stuff (instead of waiting for IO).

Comment: So it's not a **_bad_** thing, then? Yes, my loops are endless, the manager and nodes are constantly checking the specific directories for relevant files. In the final implementation in my main project the manager will be constantly monitoring for various forms of input (IMAP, STDIN, XMPP, Web, Voice, etc.) and distributing these inputs as "jobs" to other nodes in the cluster to be processed, so that I can use true parallel computing (i.e. using a node's "entire" CPU for one job). I will update the question.

Comment: Putting a small sleep inside the loop will improve CPU enormously without adding latency, as long as these things are I/O bound anyway.

Comment: Monitoring directories should definitely not use 100% CPU time. How are you doing it?

Comment: You could use [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) to monitor files/directories.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that in another question in the RPi Stack Exchange, it's called [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). I have a small sleep in one of them. I'll make sure each process has a sleep period of some amount of time and report back.

Comment: @syntonym I started this project with the goal in mind of not using any libraries not included in the PSL, until I've exhausted all uses of PSL modules. I am monitoring files using `os.path.listdir()`, and in my nodes I am excluding a few files in a conditional.

Comment: @spectre-d If you can answer your own question you should post an answer and choose it. That way others see that your question is already answered. I think there may be better ways to monitor for file changes, maybe I'm getting back at you later.

Comment: @spectre-d Meh. Watching files for changes with PSL only is surprisingly hard. Looks like you have to write some C to use some "better methods". 0.4% CPU time is probably good enough to not dwell into it..

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too worried about it. I have a year and a half before I knock out basics for school, then I'll start CS. I'm just being OCD about this because that's the goal I had in mind when I started programming in Feb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution (If however Sub-Optimal):**
Implemented a `time.sleep(n)` period at the end of each loop for `0.1` seconds. Brought the CPU time down to no more than 0.4%.

Still, though, I am looking for a more optimal way of reducing CPU time, without using modules not included in the Python Standard Library, I'd like to avoid using a `time.sleep(n)` period, as I want the system to be able to respond at any moment, and if the load of input files gets very high, I do not want it to be wasting time sleeping, when it could be processing the files.

My processes operate by busy waiting, so it was causing them to use excessive CPU time:

```
while True:
    files = os.path.listdir('./sub_directory/')

    if files != []:
        do_something()
```

This is the basis for each script/process I am executing.